# Android constraint layout not working as intended

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have an activity with a root tag of

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

I include 3 layout files in this activity and list them vertically. The following constraints on the middle one does not work

```
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lay1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lay3"
```

I don't understand why the middle one takes the entire screen instead of starting from the bottom of the top one and ending at top of the bottom one. Can you please help me?

The activity:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/lay1"
        layout="@layout/empty_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/lay2"
        layout="@layout/empty_linear_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lay3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lay1" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/lay3"
        layout="@layout/empty_linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

empty_linear_layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to override `layout_` parameters on an `<include>` layout, you have to specify both `layout_width` and `layout_height`. From [the developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts):

> However, if you want to override layout attributes using the `<include>` tag, you must override both `android:layout_height` and `android:layout_width` in order for other layout attributes to take effect.

So add these two lines to your second view:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

(Note that for `ConstraintLayout`, `0dp` means to match the constraints)

Answer (score 6):

Use this way. You are missing layout height and width for middle layout.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    layout="@layout/empty_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/lay2"
    layout="@layout/empty_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lay1"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/lay3"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/lay3"
    layout="@layout/empty_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
```

Comment: This worked. Why does making the view's height 0dp fix this problem?

Comment: If you don't specify it will take whole screen.

Answer (score 4):

Add these lines into your middle included layout:

```
 <include
    android:id="@+id/lay2"
    layout="@layout/something"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lay3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lay1" />
```

You were missing `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes

Comment: I don't understand the reason why I need those attributes. I already defined where everything should exactly be.

Comment: You need those to override your included layout parameters or your layout will spread all over your screen. Check ***@Ben P.*** answer